# SyntaxError, const array function

Tags: node.js

sorry, I am not very experienced with nodejs
I see the following error below.

> ```
> ERROR in ./src/ui/EditorToolbarConfig.js
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
> SyntaxError: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prosemirror12/src/ui/EditorToolbarConfig.js:
> ```
>
> Unexpected token (166:13)
>
> ```
>   164 |     '[image] Insert image': [
>   165 |       {
> > 166 |         lang('Insert image by URL'): IMAGE_FROM_URL,
> ```

I have written a separate js file i18.js:

```
let lang_list = {}
lang_list['en'] = {'Insert Table...': 'Insert Table...',
                  'Fill Color...': 'Fill Color...',}
lang_list['zh'] = {'Insert Table...': 'Insert Table...',
                  'Fill Color...': 'Fill Color...',
                  'Border Color....': 'Border Color....'}


export default function Lang(text) {
    if (text in lang_list['zh']) {
      return lang_list['zh'][text]
    }

    return text
}
```

and I wish to load this file in here EditorToolbarConfig.js:

```
import Lang from './i18n';
export const COMMAND_GROUPS = [
  {
   Lang( 'Insert image by URL'): FontTypeCommandMenuButton,
  },
  {
   Lang( '[format_size] Text Size'): FontSizeCommandMenuButton,
  }]
```

For some reason, I see the error above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use brackets for dynamic keys.

```
export const COMMAND_GROUPS = [
  {
    [Lang("Insert image by URL")]: FontTypeCommandMenuButton,
  },
  {
    [Lang("[format_size] Text Size")]: FontSizeCommandMenuButton,
  },
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This simple syntax error has driven me crazy...